# Determine the optimal number of biclusters

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have recently performed K-means biclustering on a matrix of absolute correlation coefficient values. However, the biclustering algorithm requires the number of biclusters (k) to be defined as an input. Is there any good method to determine the optimal number of biclusters(k)?

I know from before that many use a silhouette score to estimate the optimal number of clusters but I have only heard that people have used it when performing hierachical clustering. Can the silhouette score also be applied to biclusters as well? Is there any other method to define an optimal number of biclusters? Could a mean squared residue score be used for this?

The biclustering algorithm generated biclusters along the diagonal such that a row or column will never belong to more than one bicluster.